# Establish bot to bot communication in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, facebook-chatbot

I have 2 published bots in Azure. Now, I would like to establish communication between bots.

Using Skill bot concept, I can able send message from parent bot(Bot1) to child bot (Bot2). once Bot2 received the message it throwing below error:

> Error 403 - This web app is stopped.
>   The web app you have attempted to reach is currently stopped and does not accept any requests. Please try to reload the page or visit it again soon.
>
> If you are the web app administrator, please find the common 403 error scenarios and resolution here. For further troubleshooting tools and recommendations, please visit Azure Portal.

Also , I am getting below error at Bot1:

> [onTurnError]: Error: Request failed with status code 500
>
> [onTurnError]: [object Object]
>
> [onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: Request failed with status code 500

I didn't find any other errors except above mentioned information /error.

please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

I look forward for your suggestions/corrections. Really appreciate for your response.

Comment: In that case you can share resource among the bot or a common API endpoint they might have. That would be good work around. So far I know no ready framework is not available for that you have to integrate some techniques. Let me know if you need some more details